# Simple sticky <div> on scroll isn't sticking (using stickUp)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

The JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EKG3r/
My head tag:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="stickUp.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="stickUp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('.sticky').stickUp();
            });
          });
</script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arbutus+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="icon" 
          type="image/png" 
          href="http://www.electrobureau.com/1/favicon.ico">
    <title>
        electro bureau | 1-1 an introduction
    </title>

</head>
```

The blue bars just refuse to stick on scroll, though. I'm sure the problem is incredibly simple, but I can't get to the bottom of it. Any insight is deeply appreciated.

Comment: can someone explain to me why they would wrap a `$(document).ready()` in a self-invoking function like `jQuery(function($) ...`

Answer (score 1):

Your reference wasn't working so there is no `stickUp` method defined.

If you take the code from [Stickup](https://github.com/LiranCohen/stickUp) and paste it, it works: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKG3r/1/)

Comment: It's working in the Fiddle! Does the code in stickup.js just go in a <script> tag in the head to make it work? I'm having trouble incorporating what you did into my actual file. This is my first foray into web design, so one more little nudge forward would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes Tony, include this on your page: `<script src="js/stickUp.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Tony Yes, looks like electrobureau.com/1/stickUp.js currently contains the JavaScript you're looking for. That reference should work as intended.

Comment: @user1506980 but it isn't, and it's driving me crazy! http://www.electrobureau.com/1/1.html

Comment: @Tony Change your jquery reference from 1.4.2 to 1.10.1 or something recent: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js Then you should be okay.